# Parsing Merriam Webster JSON data attributes wrapped in a double array?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I am attempting to get the definition of a word using the documentation from Merriam Webster's API - https://dictionaryapi.com/products/json#sec-2.def

The documentation shows the structure of the JSON response from the server, and I have been able to successfully parse the raw data into a just an array containing the "sense" object.

Screenshot of code and parsed data
[image]

My issue is being able to access the "sense" JSONObject, since I am currently in an array, I can't access the sense object.  I have tried adding .getJSONArray(0) and .getJSONObject(0) after my code and both of those solutions did not work.

How can I continue parsing this JSON I currently have to the "dt" string?

```
                    JSONArray merriamResults = data.getJSONArray("Merriam")
                    .getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONArray("def")
                    .getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONArray("sseq")
                    .getJSONArray(0)
                    .getJSONArray(0);
```

Comment: post your json here lets have a look...never seen double arrays...

Comment: You can see in the screenshot that value for key "dt" is this [["text","(bc)firmly built or constituted etc."]]

Comment: ok..give me a few mins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here.

```
String json = "{\"def\":[\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "    \"sseq\":[\n" +
                "      [\n" +
                "        [\n" +
                "          \"sense\",\n" +
                "          {\n" +
                "            \"dt\":[[\"text\",\"{bc}a {a_link|backward} somersault especially\n" +
                "              in the air\"]]\n" +
                "          }\n" +
                "        ]\n" +
                "      ]\n" +
                "    ]\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "]}";

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            String dt = jsonObject.getJSONArray("def")
                    .getJSONObject(0)
                    .getJSONArray("sseq")
                    .getJSONArray(0)
                    .getJSONArray(0)
                    .getJSONObject(1)
                    .getJSONArray("dt")
                    .getJSONArray(0)
                    .getString(1);
            Log.i("jsondata", dt);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

my log:

```
 12-02 21:38:12.316 14174-14174/com.example.pemba.sample I/jsondata: {bc}a {a_link|backward} somersault especially
                      in the air
```

Comment: hey can you upvote my answer as well? I'm going for a bounty question.